# Getting the Row index of a HTML table from table click event - JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Can someone please help me crack this? I have a HTML table with an event when clicked to show a dialog. I also want to get the row index of the clicked row, but it only outputs something different.

```
//script for the table event
 <script>
    $(function() {
       $( "#table").click(function(){

           $( "#dialog-modal1" ).dialog({
              height: 140,
              modal: true,
              title:"Search Item",
              width : 440,
              position: {my: "top", at: "bottom", of: "#table"}
            });
           $( "#dialog-modal1" ).show();
           
           var row = $('<tr></tr>').text($(this).index());
           alert(row);
           
        });
     });
</script>
```

The dialog shows as expected when the table is clicked but the output for row index is not what I want. It always outputs ***[object Object]***. If the first row of the table was clicked, I expect the output to be ***0***, second row should be ***1*** and so on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should use `console.log(row)` instead of `alert(row)`, and watch the result in the console.

Comment: @cl3m console.log(row) outputs  **[tr]** .Still not what I want.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code. 

1. Inside your 'click' handler, the 'this' is actually the `table` element, and not the `tr`.

2. The `row` var is a `tr`, and `tr`'s can't contain text, only `td` or `th`...

3. You see the `[object Object]` because the `row` var is well... an object. You probably wanted to alert the `.index()` value...

4. Check out my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem  is you're binding a click event to the whole table.

```
$( "#table").click(function() { ...
```

Try

```
$("#table tr").click(function () { ...
```

Which means you're binding the event to each row in the table. Now inside the callback `this` will represent the row that was clicked.

You also don't need to use alert (as suggested by @cl3m) or even create a tr to output the index. You should be able to simply call:

```
console.log($(this).index());
```

and see the result in your browser's debugger.

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/860b9t73/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ronency/x5sspb70/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>FIRST</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SECOND</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>THIRD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('tr').click(function(){
  var $tr = $(this);
  $('#result').html("index clicked: " + $tr.index());
});
```